# CoroutineScope cancel listener

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm performing some work in a class that is using a Scope:

```
class MyClass(val scope: CoroutineScope) {

  private val state: StateFlow<Int> = someFlow()
    .shareIn(scope, started = SharingStared.Eagerly, initialValue = 0)

  fun save() {
    scope.launch {
      save(state.value)
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to clean up when the scope is cancelled. What is the best way to do this? I could come up with this, but that doesn't really sound stable.

```
init {
  scope.launch {
    try { delay(10000000000000) }
    finally { withContext(Noncancellable) { save(state.value) } }
  }
}
```

---

Edit: I've modified my snippet to more reflect what I'm doing. The `state` Flow updates several times per second, and when I invoke the `save()` method I want to save the state to disk (So I don't want to do this every time the state changes).

Next to that, I want to save the state when the scope is cancelled (i.e. at the very end). This is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: What is it that you would like to clean up? All started coroutines will be cancelled upon scope cancellation, so all the code running in them will throw `CancellationException`. Using `finally` or `use { ... }` blocks in the code of those coroutines will automatically clean up.

Comment: @Joffrey I've made an edit!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I got it now. I guess in that case, there is most likely some kind of lifecycle that the scope is bound to (where you actually cancel it). I think it might be more appropriate to hook into that lifecycle directly instead of indirectly through the scope.

Comment: Yes that is correct, though I was hoping something like this would be possible.

Comment: I added a "cleaner" alternative to your current workaround in my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such "onCancellation" mechanism on `CoroutineScope` to my knowledge. However, there is [Job.invokeOnCompletion](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/invoke-on-completion.html?query=abstract%20fun%20invokeOnCompletion(handler:%20CompletionHandler):%20DisposableHandle). So if you really want to do this, you can extract the `Job` instance from the scope's context and register a callback there:

```kotlin
val job = scope.coroutineContext.job // this fails if there is no job
job.invokeOnCompletion { cause ->
    if (cause is CancellationException) {
        // that's a normal cancellation
    }
}
```

Note that there can be coroutine scopes without a job, so make sure you're not using such a fancy scope there if you're using this code.

Now, in general, clean up can be "prepared" on the spot when executing the code that requires cleanup. For instance, using an input stream with `use { ... }` or closing resources with `finally` blocks.
This will be automatically honored on cancellation (or any other failures, btw), because cancellation of the scope simply generates `CancellationException`s inside running coroutines.

Another way to approach this is to do the cleanup you need at the same place where you cancel the scope.

If you really want to use a workaround like your current parallel coroutine, you can use [awaitCancellation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-cancellation.html) instead of a huge delay:

```kotlin
init {
  scope.launch {
    try { awaitCancellation() }
    finally { withContext(Noncancellable) { save(state.value) } }
  }
}
```

But I don't find it very appealing tbh.

Comment: Thanks for the `awaitCancellation` call! I'll see what I figure out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Exception handler

```
// Destroy service when completed or in case of an error.
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    Log.e("CoroutineExceptionHandler Error", exception.message!!)
    stopSelf(startId)
}
```

Then you can use this Handler as

```
scope.launch(handler){
// do stuff
}
```

`handler` will be called **only if an exception is thrown**

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. How would I use this in my case?